# How to carry the Torah (which way to go)

Tags: halacha, minhag, sources-mekorot

I heard 2 ideas
1. When coming go the shortest way, when leaving go the longest way.
2. Always turn right

So what needs to be done?
Sources for both ideas, and what to do, please.

Comment: What I found http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2894

Comment: Definitely don't wander around the entire building, as I've seen in some places. The Torah doesn't honor you by coming to you; you honor it by coming to it.

Comment: @DoubleAA +1 source please

Comment: @DoubleAA Shulchan Aruch does mention that it is proper to kiss the Torah. (Haveto locate it.) IIRC, correctly, it doesn't seem to be a requirement, but prob. part of the mitzvah of honoring the Torah. With that mitzvah in mind, there are many handicapped and elderly in shuls who would miss out on this opportunity if the Torah did not come to them. You've seen the person carry the Torah to another floor while it was being taken out?

Comment: @DanF "Shulchan Aruch does mention that it is proper to kiss the Torah." No it doesn't. And if a handicapped person can't come, he is Oneis and exempt.

Comment: @DoubleAA why is the bima located closer to the congregation should it not by right by the Aron and whoever wants should come close?

Comment: @DoubleAA נכון שכל אחד מהקהל יגש אל הספר תורה כדי לנשקו בידיו או בפיו, **אבל אין זה מן הראוי שמוליך הספר תורה יושיט את הספר תורה לכל אחד ואחד כדי שינשקו, אלא בעת הליכתו לתיבה, יגשו מהקהל וינשקו את הספר תורה. ומותר להקיף את אולם בית הכנסת, כדי לעבור דרך ארוכה יותר אל התיבה**. [אור זרוע, רמ''א ס''ס קמט. ילקוט יוסף, הלכות קריאת התורה, עמוד ח].  http://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.143.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Almost all the references in this answer were added thanks to @hazoriz. I am grateful to him)

See SA OC 134, 2 in [Baer Heytev sk 4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x507) (from  [Bet Yosef 128](http://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef,_Orach_Chaim.128.29.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) [.17](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x281)) :

When one get Sefer out from the Aron,  if the Aron is on the East side, and the Bima on the West side,  one would skirt round the northern side which is his right side.  When one get back the ST to the Aron,  one would skirt round the Southern side which is his right side. **But The Magen Avraham  ([141, sk 7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x518))  said that to get out the  ST and for reading one needs to take a short way.*** But the Peri Megadim ([Eshel Avraham, sk 7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x687) in name of the Levush disagree with the comparison between the man who was called to read and the Chazan with the Sefer Torah, who need always turn right). Rabbi Israel Meir Kagan in [Mishna Berura sk 25 and Shaar Hatsiun sk 30](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=43) ruled as the Peri Megadim.

Shorter length ways are mentioned for this  for the man who is called to read Torah. It is in siman  141,  7. To come rapidly makes honor to the congregation and to the Tora,  to get away by a length way would demonstrate that the man is freed from a burden.

---

*The MA reports a Bet Yosef in siman 128.I found the issue of Est --> North --> West |-->South --> Est for the ST,  See [Machatsit Hashekel sk 7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x518), who ask that lechaora, the Bet Yosef is not a proof for the opinion of the Magen Avraham.

Comment: מחצית השקל on magen avrham on the page askes your question

Comment: ערוך השלחן 141.10 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=249&hilite=

Comment: mishnra berruah http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.141.25

Comment: Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef  וראוי להוליך את הספר תורה מן ההיכל אל התיבה כשהוא פתוח, ופני נושא הספר תורה יהיו אל העם, ואחוריו אל ההיכל, והולך לצד ימין שלו, שהוא צד שמאל של ההיכל, וכך הולך סביב והספר תורה בידו עד שיגיע אל התיבה. ואף שהיא דרך ארוכה, כיון שהיא דרך ימין למוליך הספר תורה, ראוי לעשות כן. ובחזרה יחזירנו להיכל בדרך הקצרה, כדי שלא יצטרך להקיף כל כך http://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.143.9

Comment: Shar Tzion on the above Mishna Berura  (ואפשר דבס"ת לעולם עולה בדרך ימין אפילו אם היא דרך ארוכה
(ל) דביחיד שעולה לתורה הטעם משום כבוד הצבור ומשום  כבוד התורה וכמ''ש בפנים משא''כ הכא לא שייך זה [פמ''ג]:
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=43

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x687 the pri megadim

Comment: @hazoriz fixed.

Comment: I'm assuming that if the shul and Aron are not aligned in that exact direction stated. (In my shul, the Aron faces south, e.g.) one would "rotate" the above directions? Or did he also mention "right" and "left" as general directions, somewhere?